# Making @for loop with iteration in sass

Tags: css, sass

Im trying to make a loop with sass iteration.
This is my scss code:

```
@for $i from 1 through 4{
  &:nthchild(#{$i}){
    animation: xfade 24s 24s - $i * 6 infinite;
  }
}
```

And this is my output:

```
#slideshow:nthchild($i) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 24s 23s infinite;
  animation: xfade 24s 23s infinite;
}

#slideshow:nthchild($i) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 24s 22s infinite;
  animation: xfade 24s 22s infinite;
}

#slideshow:nthchild($i) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 24s 21s infinite;
  animation: xfade 24s 21s infinite;
}

#slideshow:nthchild($i) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 24s 20s infinite;
  animation: xfade 24s 20s infinite;
}
```

This is my desired result:

```
#slideshow .slide:nth-child(1) {
-webkit-animation: xfade 24s 18s infinite;
animation: xfade 24s 18s infinite;
}
#slideshow .slide:nth-child(2) {
-webkit-animation: xfade 24s 12s infinite;
animation: xfade 24s 12s infinite;
}
#slideshow .slide:nth-child(3) {
-webkit-animation: xfade 24s 6s infinite;
animation: xfade 24s 6s infinite;
}
#slideshow .slide:nth-child(4) {
-webkit-animation: xfade 24s 0s infinite;
animation: xfade 24s 0s infinite;
}
```

I didnt find any answers online that clearly said how to properly write @for loops. I found a bunch in the older .sass, but I dont know how to translate that to .scss since I'm a newbie.

Comment: strange, when I put your SASS code into [http://www.sassmeister.com/](http://www.sassmeister.com/) It shows the desired result.

Comment: Seems like the for loop is outside the .slide selector. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the output shows that the @for loop is placed inside the #slideshow selector, you should either move the for loop inside the .slide selector, or move the .slide selector in the for loop, depending on your preference:

```
#slideshow {
    @for $i from 1 through 4{
      & .slide:nthchild(#{$i}){
        animation: xfade 24s 24s - $i * 6 infinite;
      }
    }
}
```

or

```
#slideshow {
    .slide {
        @for $i from 1 through 4{
          &:nthchild(#{$i}){
            animation: xfade 24s 24s - $i * 6 infinite;
          }
        }
    }
}
```